# How to get cookie on new connection on server nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, server, nodejs-server

I'm currently using node js and express to build a webapp.

I want to check when a user changes the page to check if he has a special cookie.

For this i tried :

```
server.on('request', (req, res)=>{`
    console.log(req)
    console.log(req.cookies)
    console.log("\nCookie in serverCreate:\n")
    console.log(req.cookies)
    console.log("\nEnd Cookie in serverCreate:\n")
    if(req.cookies["user"] == undefined || req.cookies["user"]==null || req.cookies["user"]==""){
       res.redirect("/")
    }
})
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

And when I `console.log(req)`, i get an big dictionary but with out cookies.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html

Comment: Yes it's what currently i'm using

Comment: If you use it with `express`, you can use it for `middleware` this way. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DB97H9W3ks/